# statement that I don't quite understand ( setter = (o) => { }; )

Tags: c#

Right, so I've got this piece of code that initializes default values for Properties in C#.
source: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/DefValInit.aspx

Now i've rewritten it to C++ code, which sadly does not support extensions, but supplying the 
Object to the ApplyDefaultValues works as well.

One line that I was not able to rewrite to C++ are the lines containing this expression:

```
setter = (o) => { };
```

I would like to know if someone knows what this line does. Google gave no results

Comment: I'm guessing you're not talking about C++/CLI, so what C++ mechanism are you using to represent .NET delegates?

Comment: True, this piece of code is C# from the link to codeproject that I posted (it is in the zip file). I did rewrite everything from C# to C++/CLI in order to use it in my C++/CLI common library

Comment: It's a cyclops with a goatee!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

setter would be of type `Action<T>`, where the o is an instance of type T. It is a lambda, a "function" that can be called in code:

```
Action<object> setter = (o) => { };
setter(new object());
```

In this case the function does nothing, kind of a null object for something of type Action

Comment: Right, I get it, I think, the (o) is the parameter/argument list for the lambda function and {} would be the body? Just to make sure that if you call setter(new Object()); without having anything assigned to setter wouldn't cause an error.

Comment: Correct about argument and body. However, if you assign nothing to setter, using it will actually cause a null reference exception. Hence the "Null object" pattern. You can call it, there is no exception, you don't need to check for null and no side-effect happens.

Answer (score 1):

It is a lambda function that takes a single parameter and does nothing